# Parameter lengths for parameterized queries in OrmLite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

A POCO update in OrmLite executes SQL like this example:

```sql
(@P1 varchar(1043),@P2 varchar(6))
UPDATE table 
SET FILEDATA=@P1 
WHERE FILEID=@P2
```

But it leads to multiple query plans based on different `@P1` and `@P2` values with varying parameter lengths.

So, what's the best way(s) to specify data types/lengths for parameterized queries in Ormlite, so that query plans are cached properly, and avoids multiple query plans due to variable parameter lengths?

Here's a similar situation with having variable length strings: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/216330/parameterized-query-creating-many-plans

**Update**

Here's an example:

*Database Table*

```
dbo.Users
    Id (PK, int, not null)
    Email (nvarchar(150), not null)
```

*POCO*

```cs
[Alias("Users")]
public class User
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

*Code*

```cs
int userId = 1;
User user;

// get User
using (var db = DbConn.OpenDbConnection())
{
    user = db.SingleById<User>(userId);
}

// print User email (hi@example.com)
Console.WriteLine(user.Email);

// update User email
using (var db = DbConn.OpenDbConnection())
{
    user.Email = "tester@example.org";

    db.Update(User);
}
```

The update operation will result in an SQL query similar to the one I've posted at the top, with variable length of parameters. It causes multiple query plans to be created by SQL Server due to variable length of parameters. Ideally, the query should have fixed length of parameters, so that a query plan can be created, cached and reused for the same operations (e.g. User update) with varying parameter values (i.e. different email).

Comment: Please update your question with the OrmLite code you've used to create a query with variable string length params.

Comment: @mythz Hi, I've added an example with OrmLite code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Size of string parameters are now being specified from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/f78fb70601b87fe88da2cd9959bc8e7dab415a35) where it takes the default string size of the configured `StringConverter`. This change is available from v5.5.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

If needed its behavior can be overridden by [replacing the String Converter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/wiki/OrmLite-Type-Converters#enhancing-an-existing-converter) and overriding `InitDbParam()`.

Comment: Thank you @mythz! I'm guessing that now one default length in `StringConverter` will apply to all string parameters. Due to varying lengths of Unicode strings across POCOs fields, would you recommend configuring `StringConverter` to use `nvarchar(MAX)`?

Comment: I meant, would it be best to just set `converter.StringLength = 4000;` so that all string parameters have the leeway as well as query plan cacheability?

Comment: I like the way a `StringLength` attribute decoration is possible per field, as in the `GameItem` POCO under https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#create-tables-schemas. Can it be used as a way to have per field string length for full flexibility, that translates to fixed parameter length in queries as well, rather than configuring one default through `StringConverter`?

Comment: @Nick I'd just leave the default length behavior, it will use 4000 if Unicode is configured otherwise defaults to 8000 and if the string value is >8000 it will use the string.Length. No the string length is not property dependent, it uses the configured String Converter length.

Comment: It works! Got the v5.5.1 pre-rel package (which now defaults to varchar/nvarchar(4000) for all string parameters). Thank you once again for a quick resolve. This is huge for ORM & database performance.

Comment: By the way, for string values >8000, you can probably optimize it as well with varchar/nvarchar(MAX).

Comment: @Nick We already use N/VARCHAR(MAX) for Column Definitions in SQL Server but you can't use it for DB parameters, it needs to be an `int` if it's specified.

Comment: No worries. I'm using the MyGet package for now, but just curious, how long is it generally before a pre-release on MyGet lands as a release on NuGet?

Comment: @Nick There's no set timeline, it's whenever the end of a release is ready which typically happens every few months.

Comment: Alright, and is the MyGet package safe for production use, also considering if it's possible to get NuGet package restore to work with MyGet packages at ms/build time?

Comment: @Nick Yes it’s just a point in time release that goes through the same CI and test suite as the official NuGet packages except that it’s published to MyGet instead of NuGet.